# TypeScript - custom type guard

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function that checks if an object is a "plain object" - that is, it's not an instance of any class, an object initialized like `let x = { a: 1 };` I want to add a type guard to this function, to `assert` that the checked value matches an `interface` `([key: string]: any)`.

For some reason, the function does not narrow the type. Perhaps it is because "plain object" as I defined it and `[key: string]:` any are not the same thing at all (e.g. an instance of a class could also match `[key: string]: any`). Nevertheless, I want my `isPlainObject()` function to assert that if successful, the value matches `[key: string]: any`).

This is what I tried in the playground. I also included a "handbook" example to check for a specific property - which works.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgCYQB4QweQCMArCBMZAbwChk7kBtAawgE8AuZAZzClAHMAupzghW1AL7VqoSLEQoAYgHtlRUuSq16MVZwBEhOFH2TpAenPIAKgAtgXZAHdlUJo4C0yUchxwAtgAOADYoMFDK-shgtii2ohiEqkzUCMogPMgOKmokZBQAvMgAFABucMEArhAiYgCUnOVVKA7IOer5yAUAfCXadGCsgRDKMMhN1V0FRQDkynnkM-3IAGQr4xWTAITTyCCVwcHLa9FDI2Nlmyhwju0LYHUAdLrKyDuzlZgQMKB4S3UAbgsACpgbRgcgAMKxBBMLJjGIoCYtRxwZD6EJwUD6ZAAKTg5QAygg%20IEKPMNBRQMAwMAKsAAF54Zw02xUZASEogZRUjJgURIZCjbxiZAIYI3Lh1cHIGXobwYDA04DpaKvRHIKCfWn%20FAIGFMAA00Xsjhgn3IKpA3FsygOGG8XC40AoMTgrtisuQEOM-EquvAyH87v1EEc6CwuAI9yy4Gg8CQMvB5lS6UyDgAChLQB1NEVLs1aqwGhtmllw18o7nCr1istBsNhciprMKfklvRVutm%2089gcjp2TsjHmk%20VryK4W8hq8d1tXHvwIGAMxEwDyzvgYAXqnUp-PAqv18NqIDpNRzSBLarIDwADzWbrbmo2EvWLTLYAXbKqatPuq7mhO07UdMmwLpS2qAFkEsGxVjaH8Yy8GlnFcdxlikD8vy4LMsRAX9kX-LQgPoECKDAopkSgmC3y8DBlDDEAZgoFw3HQ6ROygJdKiga1KOkCQgA)

```
interface IndexedObject {
    [key: string]: any
}

interface FooObject {
    foo: "bar"
}

// This works - an example from the handbook
const isFooObject = (value: any): value is FooObject => (
    typeof value === 'object'
    && value !== null
    && typeof (value as FooObject).foo !== 'undefined'
);

/**
 * Check if the value is a "plain" JavaScript object initialized
 * with { } (not instance of any class)
 * 
 * In addition to the runtime check, this function should assert that the 
 * argument matches IndexedObject interface
 * 
 */
const isPlainObject = (value: any): value is IndexedObject => (
    typeof value === 'object'
    && value !== null
    && value.constructor === Object
    && Object.getPrototypeOf(value) === Object.prototype
);


function test<T>(value: T): T {

    if (isFooObject(value)) {
        const x = value; // T & FooObject - it works
    }

    if (isPlainObject(value)) {
        const x = value; // T - doesn't work
    }

    return value;

}
```

Update1:

I think I'm not going to use a type guard here, as the IndexedObject is too broad and can produce unexpected results. This would tell TypeScript that otherwise the value never matches IndexedObject - which is not desirable. I will use inline assertions instead.

Unless it is possible to define a type that would match "plain object"?

Nevertheless, I'm still curious why the type guard doesn't work. Also, if I return the value inside if block, after the if block the type will be never - [playground 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgCYQB4QweQCMArCBMZAbwChk7kBtAawgE8AuZAZzClAHMAupzghW1AL7VqAegBUc2nOQBhABZkmyYDGRgNyAG5wANgFcUwLsjjIARAAcTcUHeQApOMYDKCPg4oAexIyClBgMGBTYAAvPGQAdwi1KmQJZAAKEECwkB5RJGRA3VFWZARnLi4ASiVkOvQbDAwI4ECQPUC9AygzcGAAWxQEDQQmABpuq2QYPvI2jq41QLMTDBsq6Ap9OG2DOrgofjMh8GQB3ZGIa3QsXAIQ8m1waHgkOqUZagR2nm0uAAKzlARFITwAvJljOYICIxNVONCLP80JgcHhQaFkOCAHyZWj0MCsBwQYpGUzI8FU5AAcmCYLANIJdAAZCzyTDkABCakgVYmZnINkciwAOh%20eV4ZnIgSg2OpmPIguFirAov4EDAAKgORyxIg%20BgGSREGq8shqtFDh1YD1JOo1QA3NJqLMQPN2nprmAADwAFRxxopsOQfoRoao0no2l0GSsQJcIFVQZh1TNNGj0Ylf2w2JFEEdyBkMgjAFptBQMIFriAaRQErKmILo1BNWYoB0Tc7o1JBUSSchc5D%206TdF2iyWQBBDNBJgk1GVpjswAB%20KP0Vtgdud4POyRAA)

Comment: I think I should not be using a type guard here and instead, do inline type assertion. IndexedObject interface is too broad for this function and can result in unexpected things - e.g. if it actually worked, TypeScript would assume that after the if { } the type cannot match IndexedObject - which wouldn't be true here.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm still puzzled on why this does not work, and I have just tested an even edgier case - where if I return the value within the if { } block, after the block, the typeof value will be never.  New playground case: shorturl.at/abqEH

Comment: This might be a bug. It seems like it just ignores the type because the properties are typed as `any`, which might not register as "meaningful". If you change the property type to `number` for example, it will register. Btw, types like that can be written using the helper `Record` (here `Record<string, any>`).

Comment: I submitted an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40990

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but the fact that generics are involved appears to make it swallow the type. As noted in my comment, this seems like a bug.

```
function testTypeGuard<T>(value: unknown): value is T
{
    return true; // Lies
}

function genericFunction<T>(value: T)
{
    if (testTypeGuard<Record<string, any>>(value))
        console.log(value); // T
    if (testTypeGuard<Record<number, any>>(value))
        console.log(value); // T
    if (testTypeGuard<Record<any, string>>(value))
        console.log(value); // T & Record<any, string>
    if (testTypeGuard<Record<any, number>>(value))
        console.log(value); // T & Record<any, number>
    if (testTypeGuard<Record<string, string>>(value))
        console.log(value); // T & Record<string, string>
    if (testTypeGuard<Record<number, string>>(value))
        console.log(value); // T & Record<number, string>
}

// No generics:
const value: unknown = {};
if (testTypeGuard<Record<string, any>>(value))
    console.log(value); // Record<string, any>
if (testTypeGuard<Record<number, any>>(value))
    console.log(value); // Record<number, any>
if (testTypeGuard<Record<any, string>>(value))
    console.log(value); // Record<any, string>
if (testTypeGuard<Record<any, number>>(value))
    console.log(value); // Record<any, number>
if (testTypeGuard<Record<string, string>>(value))
    console.log(value); // Record<string, string>
if (testTypeGuard<Record<number, string>>(value))
    console.log(value); // Record<number, string>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, it only seems to act weird inside the generic, so it's probably a bug. shorturl.at/nqOU3 
You probably know it, I would just like to clarify that there is nothing wrong with your example above. It has to be T & "type", rather than just "type" - otherwise, it would break the generic. Just pointing this out for clarification as it sounds from your answer that this is a bug too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this

```
typeof value === 'object'
```

as type guard in typescript, it does not function as a type guard. It is a valid javascript syntax, but for typescript type guard, you should have used

```
 value instanceof Object
```

[image]